# Add Images to TableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uitableview, swift

Hi there Stackoverflow.

I want to add Images to my TableView. No code I found worked so far, it would be super-awesome if someone can finally help me. (Yeah, I'm trying this since 2 months now. All tipps just don't work out if I insert it into my code… Am I just this stupid?)

```
Candy(IMAGE:"1.png", giftig:"Echium vulgare", category:"Chocolate", name:"Nadelholz-Häubling", beides:"Nadelholz-Häubling Echium vulgare")
```

It simply doesen't work if I add

```
cell.ImageView!.image = candy.image
```

The error:

```
**'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'ImageView'**
```

Unlimited Thanks to the one that can FINALLY solve my issue.

Sincerly,
Tine

Comment: Use imageView instead of ImageView

Comment: 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'UiImage'. I declared a variable but it doesen't work :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete this line `cell.ImageView!.image = candy.image`. Try this,
[update: change candy.image thanks to Bluehound]

```
let xOffset: CGFloat = 10
let contentViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: candy.image)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, CGFloat(0), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(30))

cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: 'UiView' does not have a member named 'addSubView'. I could cry. :'/

Comment: Lets try it again. addSubview: not addSubView: I capitalized it wrong

Comment: cell does have an imageView property so there is nothing wrong wrong with that besides the capitalization, but the key here is `UIImage(named: candy.image`

Comment: It doesen't load the corresponding image, but it does compile! I also updated the sourcecode file on my original post if you might check the source files. I also tried "imageView.image = UIImage(named: candy.image)" (instead of candy.name) and also in my array "image:"1.png" and "image:"1". So far no luck :(

Comment: Now i got a weird glitch. If i scroll up or down to refresh the cells, "1.png" appears as the whole cell. I begin to hope that we can finally solve this…

Comment: Sorry what was your intention? I thought you wanted "1.png" to appear as the whole cell. So you wanted it to appear in upper half of the cell?

Comment: Hey Bigman. No I wanted it to show on the left side of the cells. (At the green "2". I included a screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qw1ulyzsy0sdri/screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: It works. Only one problem left. The right image is only showing after I swipe up (that the cell dissapear). If the cell is visible again, the right image is shown. How to make it right at start up? Edit: When I search in the tableview, the image is also not shown. :/

Comment: Yes, the text is showing up correctly. Only the image is loaded after re-appearing of the cell.

Comment: I modified the code again. How about now? Will the image show at start up?

Comment: Sir, you are A W E S O M E. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help. Hero of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a custom cell with an image placeholder?  This would be much easier to prototype.  Here is an example that might help:  http://www.seemuapps.com/tutorial-custom-uitableview-cell

Comment: I tried such a tutorial before and cannot get it to work. Weeks of try-and-error passed. I would appreciate it SO much if somebody can help me with correcting my code right at the source, because the implementation is my biggest problem.